# Download Audio and Video offline for Educational pourposes

Tags: download, ubuntu-14.04, audio-streaming, video-capture

I run an offline educational center in Africa. Given the cost of internet access. It is very costly to download tutorial videos and educational material via Internet. However during the Night the internet service provider offers free internet access. I have set up an UBUNTU 12.0 System in Africa. Link via Satellite. I am now looking for a way to auto download Youtube, google free books,  and other videos and audio (eg. Kahn tutorials) in Night and makes them available offline during the day. For educational purposes.

Any ideas of Linux based application that can help me automate this process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use https://projects.gnome.org/gwget/
Gwget it's a download manager for the Gnome Desktop . The main features are: Resume: By default, gwget tries to continue any download.

Comment: Hi Kawas. I have tried to install this app on Ubuntu 14.10 It is not going.. try to compile.. it getting error Makefile:386: recipe for target 'gwget-application.o' failed. Any other idea?

Comment: Do you have OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Try this:

wget -O flareget-amd64.deb 

http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/flareget/flareget_3.1-36_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i flareget-amd64.deb

sudo apt-get -f install;rm flareget-amd64.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution.. is much closer to what I am looking for :: YouTube-DL
http://www.tecmint.com/install-youtube-dl-command-line-video-download-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

wget -O flareget-amd64.deb

http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/flareget/flareget_3.1-36_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i flareget-amd64.deb

sudo apt-get -f install;rm flareget-amd64.deb

Comment: What kind of code is that? I am getting a command I have never seen before

Comment: Copy and past these sentences in your terminal

Comment: Looks better now.. I just download the application. and setting it up now

Comment: Is the name of the application uGet after install?

Comment: The programe is not downloading any videos